# Angular sort result of service

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, sorting, object

I've to sort the result of my post function.
there's the post function:

```
    findQuotation(queryParams: QueryParamsModel): Observable<QueryResultsModel> {
    return this.http.post<QueryResultsModel>(API_QUOTATIONS_URL + '/list', queryParams);}
```

These one return me an array of object like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aGsX.png)

I call the service's function in ngrx effect like this:

```
    @Effect()
loadRolesPage$ = this.actions$
    .pipe(
        ofType<QuotationsPageRequested>(QuotationActionTypes.QuotationsPageRequested),
        mergeMap(({ payload }) => {
            this.store.dispatch(this.showPageLoadingDistpatcher);
            const requestToServer = this.quotationService.findQuotation(payload.page);
            const lastQuery = of(payload.page);
            return forkJoin([requestToServer, lastQuery]);
        }),
        map(response => {
            console.log('response', response);
            const result: QueryResultsModel = response[0];
            const lastQuery: QueryParamsModel = response[1];
            this.store.dispatch(this.hidePageLoadingDistpatcher);

            return new QuotationsPageLoaded({
                quotations: result.items,
                totalCount: result.totalCount,
                page: lastQuery
            });
        }),
    );
```

I would like to sort this server response by created_at(Date object) from the mort recent.

Comment: sort these by?? date or quotation number or id??

Comment: and also include the code where you are invoking this function in service..

Comment: @Supercool. Sorry i cut a part of my post. I'd like to sort by created_at (Date)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

After subscribing to function of service

```
result.sort((a,b)=> new Date(b.created_at).valueOf() - new Date(a.created_at).valueOf());
```

Run this snippet to check if it works

```js
let results=[{quotationNumber:"1122", created_at:"2020-03-08T01:00:00.000Z"},{quotationNumber:"1522", created_at:"2020-03-08T09:00:00.000Z"},{quotationNumber:"1222", created_at:"2020-03-01T02:00:00.000Z"},{quotationNumber:"1322", created_at:"2020-03-05T08:00:00.000Z"},{quotationNumber:"1422", created_at:"2020-02-05T08:00:00.000Z"}];
results.sort((a,b)=>new Date(b.created_at).valueOf() - new Date(a.created_at).valueOf());
console.log(results);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your repsonses!
I get this error: 'The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type'

Comment: Yes, it works!
I now have an other problem with TypeScript but my initial problem is solved.
Thanks a lot Supercool :)

Answer (score 0):

The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the sorted array. The default sort order is ascending, built upon converting the elements into strings, then comparing their sequences of UTF-16 code units values.

```
arr.sort([compareFunction])
```

**compareFunction** Specifies a function that defines the sort order. If omitted, the array elements are converted to strings, then sorted according to each character's Unicode code point value.

If **compareFunction** is not supplied, all non-**undefined** array elements are sorted by converting them to strings and comparing strings in UTF-16 code units order. For example, "banana" comes before "cherry". In a numeric sort, 9 comes before 80, but because numbers are converted to strings, "80" comes before "9" in the Unicode order. All **undefined** elements are sorted to the end of the array

If `compareFunction` is supplied, all non-undefined array elements are sorted according to the return value of the compare function (all undefined elements are sorted to the end of the array, with no call to compareFunction). If a and b are two elements being compared, then:

- If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns less than 0, sort `a` to an index lower than `b` (i.e. a comes first).
- If `compareFunction(a, b)`   returns 0, leave `a` and `b` unchanged with respect to each other,   but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the   ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behavior, thus, not all   browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect
  this.
- If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns greater than 0, sort `b` to an   index lower than `a` (i.e. b comes first).
- `compareFunction(a, b)` must    always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a  and b as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are returned,   then the sort order is undefined.

So, the compare function has the  following form:

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion) {
    return 1;
  }
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
}
```

To compare numbers instead of strings, the compare function can simply subtract b from a. The following function will sort the array in ascending order (if it doesn't contain Infinity and NaN):

```
function compareNumbers(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}
```

So in your case `new Date()` is converting your field to `Date` and `getTime()` is converting it to number (The **getTime()** method returns the number of milliseconds* since the Unix Epoch. *getTime() always uses UTC for time representation. For example, a client browser in one timezone, getTime() will be the same as a client browser in any other timezone*.)

Since now you have numbers we will use `compareNumbers` as **compareFunction**
Result:

```
 const quotations = result.items.sort((a,b)=> new Date(b.created_at).getTime() - new Date(a.created_at).getTime());

return new QuotationsPageLoaded({
   quotations: quotations,
   totalCount: result.totalCount,
   page: lastQuery
});
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding explanation of how and why the code works.